# CSS3 Background-repeat doesn't fit the pattern

Tags: css, design-patterns, repeat

I try to make a background by repeating a pattern.
Here is the pattern I used: https://www.vecteezy.com/vector-art/93065-free-vector-zig-zag-backgrounds

On Adobe Illustrators it's fit perfectly:

[image]

But on website doesn't fit very well:

[image]

CSS for the container:

```
color: #ae8032;
background: #001224;
background-image: url(/assets/contact_pattern.svg);
background-size: 200px;
background-repeat: repeat;
```

Somebody knows how to fix that problem?

Comment: can you share the SVG here?

Comment: @TemaniAfif https://pastebin.com/jdGFhdUh